# How to get the xpath for jobpage?

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver, scrapy

I have tried too many possibilities to get xpath for click the "Search Jobs Now" and "Search " button for to get job list page. but its not find exactly what i am expected.

Please let me know how to find click the "Search Jobs Now" and "Search" button and get the joblist page.

Note:

I checked the Web-element **'Search jobs now'** is located under **frame id= ptifrmtgtframe and name =TargetContent**. Once we switch to this frame then we will be able to click on first page button and second page button like "**Search**"

Platform : scrapy + selenium remote control + python

Here is spider code:

```
class WellsfargocomSpider(Spider):
    name = 'wellsfargo'
    allowed_domains = ['www.wellsfargo.com']
    start_urls = ['https://employment.wellsfargo.com/psp/PSEA/APPLICANT_NW/HRMS/c/HRS_HRAM.HRS_APP_SCHJOB.GBL?FOCUS=']


    #driver = webdriver.Remote('http://127.0.0.1:4444/wd/hub', desired_capabilities=webdriver.DesiredCapabilities.HTMLUNIT)
        # Create a new instance of the Firefox webdriver
    driver = webdriver.Firefox()
        # Create implicitly wait for 30
    #driver.implicitly_wait(0.5)


    def parse(self,response):

        selector = Selector(response)
        #self.driver.get('https://employment.wellsfargo.com/psp/PSEA/APPLICANT_NW/HRMS/c/HRS_HRAM.HRS_APP_SCHJOB.GBL?FOCUS=')
        driver = self.driver

        #driver = webdriver.Firefox()
        self.driver.get('https://employment.wellsfargo.com/psp/PSEA/APPLICANT_NW/HRMS/c/HRS_HRAM.HRS_APP_SCHJOB.GBL?FOCUS=');
        self.driver.switchTo().frame(self.driver.find_element_by_tag_name('TargetContent'))
        Thread.sleep(10000)
        clk = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@id='HRS_CE_WELCM_WK_HRS_CE_WELCM_BTN']")
        clk.click()

        clk1 = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@name='SEARCHACTIONS#SEARCH']")
        clk1.click()

        self.driver.switchTo().defaultContent()

        #inputElement = self.driver.find_element_by_css_selector("input.PSPUSHBUTTON")
        #inputElement.submit()
        #inputElement1 = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@name='SEARCHACTIONS#SEARCH']")
        #inputElement1.click()




        #while True:
            #next = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath(".//*[@id='HRS_APPL_WRK_HRS_LST_NEXT']")

            #try:
        links = []
        for link in selector.css('span.PSEDITBOX_DISPONLY').re('.*>(\d+)<.*'):
                #intjid = selector.css('span.PSEDITBOX_DISPONLY').re('.*>(\d+)<.*')
                    abc = 'https://employment.wellsfargo.com/psp/PSEA/APPLICANT_NW/HRMS/c/HRS_HRAM.HRS_APP_SCHJOB.GBL?Page=HRS_APP_JBPST&FOCUS=Applicant&SiteId=1&JobOpeningId='+link+'&PostingSeq=1'
                        #print abc
                    yield Request(abc,callback=self.parse_iframe, headers={"X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest"}, dont_filter=True)

                #next.click()
            #except:
                #break

        #self.driver.close()

    def parse_iframe(self,response):
        selector = Selector(response)
        url = selector.xpath('//*[@id="ptifrmtgtframe"]/@src').extract()[0]
        yield Request(url,callback=self.parse_listing_page, headers={"X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest"}, dont_filter=True)
```

Here is output:

```
C:\Users\xxxx\Downloads\wellsfargocom>scrapy crawl wellsfargo
2014-11-28 10:40:07+0530 [scrapy] INFO: Scrapy 0.24.4 started (bot: wellsfargoco
m)
2014-11-28 10:40:07+0530 [scrapy] INFO: Optional features available: ssl, http11

2014-11-28 10:40:07+0530 [scrapy] INFO: Overridden settings: {'NEWSPIDER_MODULE'
: 'wellsfargocom.spiders', 'SPIDER_MODULES': ['wellsfargocom.spiders'], 'BOT_NAM
E': 'wellsfargocom'}
2014-11-28 10:40:07+0530 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled extensions: LogStats, TelnetCons
ole, CloseSpider, WebService, CoreStats, SpiderState
2014-11-28 10:40:07+0530 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled downloader middlewares: HttpAuth
Middleware, DownloadTimeoutMiddleware, UserAgentMiddleware, RetryMiddleware, Def
aultHeadersMiddleware, MetaRefreshMiddleware, HttpCompressionMiddleware, Redirec
tMiddleware, CookiesMiddleware, ChunkedTransferMiddleware, DownloaderStats
2014-11-28 10:40:07+0530 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled spider middlewares: HttpErrorMid
dleware, OffsiteMiddleware, RefererMiddleware, UrlLengthMiddleware, DepthMiddlew
are
2014-11-28 10:40:07+0530 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled item pipelines:
2014-11-28 10:40:07+0530 [wellsfargo] INFO: Spider opened
2014-11-28 10:40:07+0530 [wellsfargo] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), sc
raped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2014-11-28 10:40:07+0530 [scrapy] DEBUG: Telnet console listening on 127.0.0.1:6
023
2014-11-28 10:40:07+0530 [scrapy] DEBUG: Web service listening on 127.0.0.1:6080

2014-11-28 10:40:09+0530 [wellsfargo] DEBUG: Redirecting (302) to <GET https://e
mployment.wellsfargo.com/psp/PSEA/APPLICANT_NW/HRMS/c/HRS_HRAM.HRS_APP_SCHJOB.GB
L?FOCUS=&> from <GET https://employment.wellsfargo.com/psp/PSEA/APPLICANT_NW/HRM
S/c/HRS_HRAM.HRS_APP_SCHJOB.GBL?FOCUS=>
2014-11-28 10:40:10+0530 [wellsfargo] DEBUG: Redirecting (302) to <GET https://e
mployment.wellsfargo.com/psp/PSEA/APPLICANT_NW/HRMS/c/HRS_HRAM.HRS_APP_SCHJOB.GB
L?FOCUS=> from <GET https://employment.wellsfargo.com/psp/PSEA/APPLICANT_NW/HRMS
/c/HRS_HRAM.HRS_APP_SCHJOB.GBL?FOCUS=&>
2014-11-28 10:40:10+0530 [wellsfargo] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://employme
nt.wellsfargo.com/psp/PSEA/APPLICANT_NW/HRMS/c/HRS_HRAM.HRS_APP_SCHJOB.GBL?FOCUS
=> (referer: None)
2014-11-28 10:40:20+0530 [wellsfargo] ERROR: Spider error processing <GET https:
//employment.wellsfargo.com/psp/PSEA/APPLICANT_NW/HRMS/c/HRS_HRAM.HRS_APP_SCHJOB
.GBL?FOCUS=>
        Traceback (most recent call last):
          File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\base.py", line 82
4, in runUntilCurrent
            call.func(*call.args, **call.kw)
          File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\task.py", line 63
8, in _tick
            taskObj._oneWorkUnit()
          File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\task.py", line 48
4, in _oneWorkUnit
            result = next(self._iterator)
          File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\scrapy-0.24.4-py2.7.egg\scrapy\uti
ls\defer.py", line 57, in <genexpr>
            work = (callable(elem, *args, **named) for elem in iterable)
        --- <exception caught here> ---
          File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\scrapy-0.24.4-py2.7.egg\scrapy\uti
ls\defer.py", line 96, in iter_errback
            yield next(it)
          File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\scrapy-0.24.4-py2.7.egg\scrapy\con
trib\spidermiddleware\offsite.py", line 26, in process_spider_output
            for x in result:
          File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\scrapy-0.24.4-py2.7.egg\scrapy\con
trib\spidermiddleware\referer.py", line 22, in <genexpr>
            return (_set_referer(r) for r in result or ())
          File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\scrapy-0.24.4-py2.7.egg\scrapy\con
trib\spidermiddleware\urllength.py", line 33, in <genexpr>
            return (r for r in result or () if _filter(r))
          File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\scrapy-0.24.4-py2.7.egg\scrapy\con
trib\spidermiddleware\depth.py", line 50, in <genexpr>
            return (r for r in result or () if _filter(r))
          File "C:\Users\sureshp\Downloads\wellsfargocom\wellsfargocom\spiders\w
ellsfargo.py", line 48, in parse
            self.driver.switchTo().frame(self.driver.find_element_by_tag_name('T
argetContent'))
        exceptions.AttributeError: 'WebDriver' object has no attribute 'switchTo
'

2014-11-28 10:40:20+0530 [wellsfargo] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
2014-11-28 10:40:20+0530 [wellsfargo] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
        {'downloader/request_bytes': 1880,
         'downloader/request_count': 3,
         'downloader/request_method_count/GET': 3,
         'downloader/response_bytes': 7190,
         'downloader/response_count': 3,
         'downloader/response_status_count/200': 1,
         'downloader/response_status_count/302': 2,
         'finish_reason': 'finished',
         'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2014, 11, 28, 5, 10, 20, 84000),
         'log_count/DEBUG': 5,
         'log_count/ERROR': 1,
         'log_count/INFO': 7,
         'response_received_count': 1,
         'scheduler/dequeued': 3,
         'scheduler/dequeued/memory': 3,
         'scheduler/enqueued': 3,
         'scheduler/enqueued/memory': 3,
         'spider_exceptions/AttributeError': 1,
         'start_time': datetime.datetime(2014, 11, 28, 5, 10, 7, 448000)}
2014-11-28 10:40:20+0530 [wellsfargo] INFO: Spider closed (finished)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is called [`switch_to`](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/api.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.WebDriver.switch_to), not `switchTo`. Here is a working example:

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get('https://employment.wellsfargo.com/psp/PSEA/APPLICANT_NW/HRMS/c/HRS_HRAM.HRS_APP_SCHJOB.GBL?FOCUS=')

# find the frame and switch to it
frame = driver.find_element_by_id('ptifrmtgtframe')
driver.switch_to.frame(frame)

# find the button and click it
button = driver.find_element_by_id('HRS_CE_WELCM_WK_HRS_CE_WELCM_BTN')
button.click()
```

Comment: Hi Alecxe, Thank you for your guidance. I can able to click the Search Jobs Now button. Its switch over to another page like "Search"  but its not click the "Search" button. I have try with this code which i have upload in the gitup link Please check this: https://gist.github.com/joshbolt/bd41a7fd17888ecea043

Comment: @joshtim good, this is a separate problem which can be elaborated into a separate question if you have difficulties. The initial problem you had, as I can see, is resolved. Please, see if the answer can be accepted. Thanks.

Comment: Sure I will trying to get it to resolved, Could you please look in to this.

Comment: @joshtim: Thats Good..! Its was switch_to. You were almost there.

Comment: Yes Rupesh, its now working as expected for "Search Jobs Now", but its not working for another page which have "Search" button.https://gist.github.com/joshbolt/bd41a7fd17888ecea043